# Missing ArduinoJson/DynamicJsonBuffer.hpp

Tags: arduino-uno, iot

I have read other posts regarding ArduinoJson that recommend using a library version no later than 5.14.3.  That recommendation is more than a year old - is it still the recommended library version?

Comment: I have only ever used ArduinoJSON 6 and never had any problems with it. Unless you *need* version 5 for compatibility with some old system then I would say use 6.

Comment: version 6 breaks backward compatibility so you can't upgrade from 5 to 6 without migrating all sketches to classes of version 6 of the library. (or using some workaround by having the version 5 of the library in a renamed folder)